# Cluj connecting airport, 2 separate tickets from same site, same airline, 1 hour between flights enough?

Tags: transit, eu-citizens

- Travelling from Larnaca (Cyprus)->Cluj (Romania) then from
  Cluj->London.
- I have two separate tickets (same airline, bought through WIZZ) and
  only 1 hour between arrival and departure.
- I have EU passport and all countries involved are in EU (for the time
  being!).
- I do not have any checked-in luggage, I only have a shoulder bag.
- WIZZ's punctuality the last week regarding this particular flight
  from Larnaca seem OK.
- Scheduled arrival in Cluj at 19:00 on a Monday.

**Is 70 minutes adequate time to catch my connecting flight ? (from touchdown to gate closing)?**

Comment: Given you must be at the gate 30 minutes before your second flight, this is really very short. Make sure you get a seat up front on the first flight. Can't even find a terminal map of that airport.

Comment: If the pictures on Google Maps are up to date, there are no contact positions for aircraft, which means all passengers need to take a bus between the aircraft to the terminal. This probably adds a good 10-15 minutes to your disembarkation time, even if you are the first off the aircraft, and also means they will probably be quite strict about the 30 minutes deadline. I also don't see any mention whatsoever of airside transit anywhere. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but it's probably quite unlikely.

Comment: Good that you had feedback from someone who knows the airport. Not quite sure why this was put on hold as "too broad" when this is actually a very, very specific question...

Comment: Don't forget to post an answer once you have attempted the transfer, letting us know if it did work out!

Comment: @jcaron I'm not familiar with Cluj, but in small airports it's pretty common to just walk to/from the aircraft.

Comment: @jpatokal given the buses visible on the satellite view on Google Maps, and the comment on the question on FlyerTalk, it seems that buses are used (though apparently not always).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. It was a bad mistake to seek help on SO on a very urgent problem. My post has been "put on hold" - orwelian speak for "we do whatever we like here and invent some excuse for you". And then censored heavily by the bureaucracy here. Thankfully I got what I needed from another forum where - it seems to me - common sense still prevails, so follow on at this link where I will also post what happens. Goodnight and Good Luck. https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/europe/1990188-2-tickets-same-connecting-airport-cluj-1-hour-between-flights-any-tips.html

Comment: **I have now taken the flight**. If you are interested to see what happened, please see my **report** here: https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/europe/1990188-2-tickets-same-connecting-airport-cluj-1-hour-between-flights-any-tips.html  . I can not publish it on SO because this question was "put on hold". It can not have an answer! SO failed me when I needed an answer to my urgent question which SO zealots put it "on hold" on their whim. "you pay peanuts you get monkeys" vs "you pay nothing you get capos". Will my question end in a Gulagh?...